# no NPOT issues on msvc but when on mingw-w64 the screen stays blank

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw-w64, olcpixelgameengine

I'm using [olc::PixelGameEngine](https://www.github.com/oneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/blob/master/olcPixelGameEngine.h) and I'm using the [Example Program](https://www.github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/blob/master/olcExampleProgram.cpp) except that I'm enabling STB image. on MSVC, PGE worked great for several months without any issues but recently i moved to make+mingw-w64 and I'm getting a white screen at startup. but when specifying the width and height to both be 256 it works fine, which means that my driver only supports NPOT. I want to know why on MSVC it worked but on mingw-w64 it didn't

here are the commands I'm using the build the example project

```
g++ -g3 -ggdb -m64 -I.\include\stb_image\ -DOLC_IMAGE_STB -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-switch -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-reorder -std=c++20 -c olcExampleProgram.cpp -o a.o

g++ -g3 -ggdb  a.o -o a.exe -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lShlwapi -ldwmapi -lstdc++ -lstdc++fs
```

Comment: How many videocards do you have? Maybe one app runs in an integrated one, and the other one doesn't?

Comment: just a single integrated one.

Comment: Bumping posts without any new information is generally discouraged. Try to debug it, and add any new things you discorer to the question.

Comment: Try printing `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)`, and same for `GL_RENDERER`, `GL_VERSION`. Compare them between the two apps.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
msvc -> mingw;    
Intel -> Microsoft Corporation;    
Intel(R) HD Graphics -> GDI Generic;    
2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2900 -> 1.1.0;

Comment: Weird. At this point I'd file a bug to engine developers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat can you point to a website? I'm using msys2 mingw-w64

Comment: I meant that PixelGameEngine thing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat one of the users in the discord group informed me that it compiles fine for mingw for many other users, and everyone who uses it with mingw follows the same tutorial made by another user. so it can't be caused by pge

Comment: Well, someone needs to debug it. Either you or its developer. Try making a simple GL hello world without this engine, and see what strings you get from `glGetString`. If you get the same strings as now, post your new code and we can look at it. If you get different strings, something is wrong with the engine.

Comment: yeah i got the same string. i used [this](https://github.com/vbsw/opengl-win32-example/blob/master/Main.cpp) as a hello world

Comment: Hmm. Now you probably should post a new question, that includes: this code (modified to print `glGetString` stuff), how to compile it on both MSVC and MinGW, the strings you get on both, and information about your OS, videocard and its driver.